# 2-D vector of boost::variant in C++

Tags: c++, boost-variant, 2d-vector

I'm looking to store information from a data table with multiple rows and columns. Each column houses a differing type (`int`, `double`, `std::string`, etc), which would only be known at runtime.

Is a 2-d `vector` of `boost::variant` the best way, or are there better storing mechanisms to accomplish this?

Comment: An example of what you're exactly trying to store would be helpful.  If you meant storing a single row, having multiple columns each with varying data types, a `boost::tuple` may be the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it's not clear what you're actually looking for. The answer depends on various factors:

- Assuming you have different types per column, are the types the same for
  all rows?
- Are the types known at compile time or only at run-time?

In the simplest case of the types being known at compile time and being the same for all rows, why not simply use a custom class to represent a column or a `std::tuple`?

If the types are different between different columns, you must use a omnipotent type, such as `boost::any`.
This may also be the easiest solution should the types only be known at run-time.